# I'm trying to run hitory commands on LINUX.But when I run !#, it returns not found error

Tags: linux, unix

I'm new to LINUX. I'm using LINUX thru putty 
When I run history command, I see last ran commands but when I'm trying to run them I'm getting this error...

```
266     hist
267     h
268     ls -la
269     ls -lastr
270     vi .sh_history
271     vi .
272     h
QTH614:samgw:/prod/user/home/qth614>!266
-ksh: !266: not found [No such file or directory]
/prod/user/home/614>
```

This might be necause of my putty configuration...I'm not sure.

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: It looks like the shell is trying to treat `!266` as a regular command. Are you sure that the particular `ksh` you are using (there are a few) supports `!` as a history operation? If so, it may be disabled. Is there something you have to do to enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is something I'm used to with bash, but it looks like ksh you might want to try this:

```
r 266
```

Reference: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/shell/ksh_hist3.1.html